# Windows cmd pass output of one command as parameter to another

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, pipe, command-line-arguments

In linux it is possible t do this:

```
git diff $(git status -s -b | sed -n '2p' | cut -d' ' -f2-)
```

or a simpler case

```
ls $(pwd)
```

The question is how can I achieve the same in windows? (not using a batch file,  a one liner in command prompt). Not all commands support piping so how can we evaluate one and pass result as parameter to another?

I've tried piping and `<` and `>` but none work.

```
git diff < (git status -s -b | sed -n '2p' | cut -d' ' -f2-)
```

Try that yourself it expects a file. And `|` doesn't work either as `git diff` doesn't support it

```
git status -s -b | sed -n '2p' | cut -d' ' -f2- | git diff // results in illegal seek
```

Comment: Use doublequotes in windows instead of singlequotes (as on linux).

Comment: Try escaping the pipe with `^`, i.e. `-s -b ^| sed`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no `$` operator in `cmd`.
Redirection operators (`<`, `>`, `>>`) expect files or stream handles.
A pipe `|` passes the standard output of a command into the standard input of another one.

A [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) however is capable of capturing the output of a command and providing it in a variable reference (`%A` in the example); see the following code:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`git status -s -b ^| sed -n '2p' ^| cut -d' ' -f2-`) do git diff %A
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Update `for for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (\`git status -s -b ^| sed -n '$1p' ^| cut -d" " -f3\`) do git diff %A $2 $3 $4` ($n is command line arguments for this alias) and it'll diff the right file by number from `git status` output

Comment: Everything is so simple in linux

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen I just spent better part of an hour on a 3 line BASH script because (1) `alias` just don't work in a shell script, (2) if you assign the output of a command to a variable with `var=$(cmd)` and that output has JSON in it, then the JSON gets mangled. So maybe we can agree that both BASH and WINBAT suck? :)

Comment: @bigjosh maybe cross platform `PowerShell` worth a try :)

Comment: Nothing mangles JSON in a command substitution. Something else was wrong there. (But yeah, aliases suck.)