# How can I delete all local Docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I recently started using Docker and never realized that I should use `docker-compose down` instead of `ctrl-c` or `docker-compose stop` to get rid of my experiments. I now have a large number of unneeded docker images locally.

Is there a flag I can run to delete all the local docker images & containers?

Something like `docker rmi --all --force` --all flag does not exist but I am looking for something with similar idea.

Comment: Related: [How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723111/55075).

Comment: `docker images purge` --> will remove all your docker images

Comment: With xargs: `docker image ls -q | xargs -I {} docker image rm -f {}`

Comment: @muthukumarhelius I think you mean `docker image prune` (image is singular and it's prune instead of purge).

Comment: `docker image prune --all --force`

Comment: `docker images | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -L1 docker image rm -f`

Answer (score 2137, accepted):

**Unix**

To delete all containers including its volumes use,

```
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -aq)
```

To delete all the images,

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -aq)
```

Remember, you should remove all the containers before removing all the images from which those containers were created.

**Windows - Powershell**

```
docker images -a -q | % { docker image rm $_ -f }
```

**Windows - cmd.exe**

```
for /F %i in ('docker images -a -q') do docker rmi -f %i
```

Comment: `unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a` when running `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`

Comment: @Ashutosh Chamoli: Doesn't work in CMD, works in PowerShell.

Comment: One-line variant for powershell: `docker images -a -q | % { docker image rm $_ -f }`

Comment: 「docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q) 」is real badass

Comment: you might wanna add the powershell comment posted in your answer, because i tried this several times in CMD until I read this commentby @Jack

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. Please, remove the last dash in the PowerShell command. Note that is not part of the command in @CodeStix comment. The container one liner is `docker ps -a -q | % { docker rm -vf $_ }`

Comment: @Titan, thank you. Edited. I don't have way to test in windows, should have paid more attention to comment.

Comment: Great @techtabu. BTW I'm using PowerShell Core on Manjaro.

Comment: Just optimization: in Windows we can combine it in PowerShell like: "docker image rm $(docker images -a -q)"

Comment: I kept getting `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket` so I first fixed this by using `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` then those commands were working perfectly.

Comment: I have faced an issue with AWS EC2 Instance. That instance default user is ```ubuntu```. So when I run the code that gives permission error. Then I used ```sudo docker rm -vf $(sudo docker ps -aq)``` and ```sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -aq)```

Comment: how about volumes :)

Comment: If you want to just remove volumes you can do `docker volume prune`. Here is the docs. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/

Comment: Since the question asks about Images (as opposed to containers), I feel like the top two lines of code should be switched around (so the code for images is first)

Comment: btw, do not use quotes around the `$()` in the Unix version, otherwise all image/container ids are interpreted as a single argument

Comment: I was having so many kubernetes related images from couple of year back tastings, which I was not able to remove anyhow but this command, provided in the above answer worked pretty well: "docker rmi -f $(docker images -aq)"

Answer (score 610):

Use this to **delete everything**:

```
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

> Remove all unused containers, volumes, networks and images

```
WARNING! This will remove:
    - all stopped containers
    - all networks not used by at least one container
    - all volumes not used by at least one container
    - all images without at least one container associated to them
    - all build cache
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#extended-description

Comment: Doesn't actually reclaim all the disk space, however.

Comment: @lucian303 this approach does reclaim disk space. Maybe you are facing a particular issue.

Comment: I only seem to get the desired result when I do this *and* the steps in @techtabu 's answer

Comment: unknown flag: --volumes

Comment: @lucian303 in my case the space was reclaimed only after restarting the docker

Comment: Using Windows and Docker Desktop, disk space was not reclaimed. The other solutions mentioned in the comments did not work for me. I posted an answer that helped me in reclaiming disk space.

Comment: @lucian303 It *does* reclaim disk space. In my case: `Total reclaimed space: 7.575GB`. And `docker ps -a` and `docker images` empty after this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, just claimed 280GB of free space while the accepted solution only cleaned 10GB.

Comment: It's not everything if it keeps containers in use. I have some containers that I can't seems to stop (they restart) and I have no idea where they were started from. So something that absolutely just resets Docker on a system would be the best answer imho.

Comment: It worked for me. It helped deleting the volumes too

Comment: This is the proper and clean answer. Still working in 2024. Remind take down the running containers or it won't remove the respective images.

Comment: Well this is the final blow. Reclaimed some great space.

Comment: I often use `docker system prune -af` to start with a clean slate.

Answer (score 102):

### **Here is short and quick solution I used**

Docker provides a single command that will clean up any resources — images, containers, volumes, and networks — that are dangling (not associated with a container):

```
docker system prune
```

To additionally remove any stopped containers and all unused images (not just dangling images), add the `-a` flag to the command:

```
docker system prune -a
```

---

For more details visit [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)

Answer (score 56):

```
docker image prune -a
```

> Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones. Add `-f` option to
> force.

Local docker version: 17.09.0-ce, Git commit: afdb6d4, OS/Arch: darwin/amd64

```
$ docker image prune -h
Flag shorthand -h has been deprecated, please use --help

Usage:  docker image prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused images

Options:
  -a, --all             Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'until=<timestamp>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
      --help            Print usage
```

Answer (score 20):

**Easy and handy commands**

To delete all images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a)
```

To delete containers which are in exited state

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
```

To delete containers which are in created state

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=created -q)
```

**NOTE: Remove all the containers then remove the images**

Comment: to delete all images, should be - "docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)". -q returns just the image ids

Comment: that means it has deleted those images. Recheck once again

Answer (score 13):

There is a [bug in Windows](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31253) where disk space is not reclaimed after removing the images. Rebooting Docker / Windows did not work.

In case you are using Docker Desktop, the [following](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699) worked for me. Go to Troubleshoot -> Clean / purge data. This can save you a lot of disk space, maybe more than you wanted.

[image]

Please note: this removes everything, so think twice before doing this!

Comment: It does the job.

Answer (score 10):

For Linux Ubuntu user, below worked for me. Word of Caution- It will remove all by the way.

For removing containers along with volumes associated with it, use below:

```
sudo docker rm -vf $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

For Removing images use below:

```
sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -a -q)
```

Answer (score 4):

To delete all images:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | awk {'print $3'})
```

Explanation:

> docker images -a | awk {'print $3'}

This command will return all image id's and then used to delete image using its id.

Comment: `-q` also only prints the ids

Answer (score 4):

If you need to delete *without invoking docker* (for example, if docker is broken and does not start, has been removed itself but not its images, etc):

```
systemctl stop docker  # stop docker if it was running
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

This directly removes ALL docker images/containers/volumes from the filesystem.

Comment: and also docker infrastructure files. I would NOT do that.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu what do you mean by "docker infrastructure files" ? The settings in `/etc/docker` are not affected

Comment: `ERROR: failed to update bridge store for object type *bridge.networkConfiguration: open /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db: no such file or directory`

Comment: [@ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153271/ravi) docker may need to be stopped first, e.g. `systemctl stop docker`

Answer (score 3):

To delete all images :

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

***where -a is all, and -q is return only image ids***

To remove unused images, and containers :

```
docker system prune
```

beware as if you are using docker swarm, and your local machine is joining remote swarm (as manager/worker), your local will be the deployed repo. executing this thus removes the deployed images.

Comment: That command would remove volume(s) as well that you may still be using.

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
docker rmi $(docker images -q) --force
```

Comment: You should add some explanation when leaving an answer on a post, so that others finding it later can understand it.

Answer (score 3):

To remove all images **without at least one container associated** to them

```
$ docker images prune -a
```

To get all the names of the images : `docker images -a -q` and remove **all images** using this command in the same line.

```
docker image rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

If you have images attached to at least one of the running containers, it is a good idea to stop them first.

To remove images created more than 10 days (240 h ) ago:

```
$ docker images prune -a --force --filter "until=240h"
```

You can verify by using the following command:

```
$  docker images --format 'table {{.Repository}}\t{{.Tag}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.Size}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
docker system prune
```

Comment: In my case this would remove a volume that I still use. Don't use this if you don't know what it does

Comment: 'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `xargs` (Unix only)

```
docker image ls -q | xargs -I {} docker image rm -f {}
```

Comment: 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

1. sudo docker images / docker images // list of images with id
2. `sudo docker rm image <image_id>` / `docker rm image <image_id>`

Answer (score 2):

docker image rm -f $(docker image ls -a -q)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to techtabu's accepted answer, If you're using docker on windows, you can use the following command

`for /F "delims=" %A in ('docker ps -a -q') do docker rm %A`

here, the command `docker ps -a -q` lists all the images and this list is passed to `docker rm` one by one

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225925/windows-cmd-pass-output-of-one-command-as-parameter-to-another/43226480) for more details on how this type of command format works in windows cmd.

Answer (score 1):

To delete all Docker local Docker images follow 2 steps ::

step 1 : docker images ( list all docker images with ids )

```
     example :
     REPOSITORY    TAG    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
     pradip564/my  latest 31e522c6cfe4        3 months ago        915MB
```

step 2 : docker image rm 31e522c6cfe4 ( IMAGE ID)

```
      OUTPUT : image deleted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check docker containers volume

`docker system df`

Prune all images and volumes

`docker prune --all`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command I used and put it in a batch file to remove everything:

> echo "Removing containers :" && if [ -n "$(docker container ls -aq)"
> ]; then docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq); docker
> container rm $(docker container ls -aq); fi; echo "Removing images :"
> && if [ -n "$(docker images -aq)" ]; then docker rmi -f $(docker
> images -aq); fi; echo "Removing volumes :" && if [ -n "$(docker volume
> ls -q)" ]; then docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q); fi; echo
> "Removing networks :" && if [ -n "$(docker network ls | awk '{print
> $1" "$2}' | grep -v 'ID|bridge|host|none' | awk '{print $1}')" ];
> then docker network rm $(docker network ls | awk '{print $1" "$2}' |
> grep -v 'ID|bridge|host|none' | awk '{print $1}'); fi;

Comment: That looks like a nice command but would be much easier as a human to assimilate in a shell script form and then could be versioned as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't seem to provide an easy way to **delete just the containers with "auto-generated" names**. This is my most frequent intent, so I wrote a Powershell script for it:

```
$containers = (docker container list -a).Split("`n") | % { [regex]::split($_, "\s+") | Select -Last 1 }
$containersToRemove = $containers | Where { ([regex]"^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$").IsMatch($_) }

# it's recommended to delete in batches, as too many at once can cause issues
$containersToRemove = $containersToRemove | Select-Object -First 30

foreach ($container in $containersToRemove) {
    # sync/wait-based version (slow)
    # docker container rm $container

    # async/background-process version (fast)
    Start-Process -FilePath docker -ArgumentList "container rm $container" -NoNewWindow
}
```

Take caution of course, as this script is just using a regular-expression: `^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$`

So only use it if you know that the containers you care about do not use the same format (of lowercase-word, underscore, lowercase-word); or at least only run the first two lines, run `echo $containersToRemove`, and check the list before actually executing the deletions.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker images -f dangling=true
docker image prune
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove any stopped containers and all unused images.

> docker system prune -a

To delete unused images, containers and volumes then run the following command

> docker system prune -a -f

Answer (score 0):

### To remove a subset of images

Add a [filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filter), with `-f`.

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -af <YOUR_FILTER_PATTERN> -q)
```

E.g. if `docker images` returns:

```
image3                      latest    3a371a8efe91   12 days ago    987MB
image2                      latest    cca6cd42c697   12 days ago    987MB
image1                      latest    0373470f2972   12 days ago    987MB
image0                      latest    1a99848b511f   13 days ago    987MB
node                        18        5087dac9940a   2 weeks ago     947MB
nginx                       latest    8a5e3e44915c   2 weeks ago     135MB
alpine                      latest    04eeaa5f8c35   6 weeks ago     7.46MB
hello-world                 latest    46331d942d63   11 months ago   9.14kB
```

**-f since=***

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -af since=node:18 -q)
```

will result in:

```
node                        18        5087dac9940a   2 weeks ago     947MB
nginx                       latest    8a5e3e44915c   2 weeks ago     135MB
alpine                      latest    04eeaa5f8c35   6 weeks ago     7.46MB
hello-world                 latest    46331d942d63   11 months ago   9.14kB
```

There are a few options including `since`,`before`,`label` or `reference`(pattern match). [The docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filter).

This might be useful if you have a development loop involving repeated builds, but want to keep the base OS local (e.g. node) to avoid repeated downloads.