# Cached Docker images on Hosted Linux Preview agent

Tags: docker, azure-devops

We are building docker image on VSTS by using VSTS Hosted Linux Preview agent. microsoft/aspnetcore-build image is used to build asp.net core application. Each time build is triggered, an agent is pulling microsoft/aspnetcore-build image from registry and it takes some time. We would like to avoid this, by specifying specific image pre-cached on agents.

Is there a list of container images that have been cached on Hosted Linux Preview agent? Such information is available for [Hosted VS2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) agent, but not for Linux one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No official article mentions it, I submit a user voice here: [Docker image cache on Hosted linux agent](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34488064-docker-image-cache-on-hosted-linux-agent) that you can vote and follow.

Comment: Voting hos been closed. How nice. This is really annoying. At least self hosted should be discounted / package deals or something. Can you cache on self hosted builds? Maybe that will speed up the builds then ok.. whatever. But I have to wait 5 minutes to build a simple docker image now of which only 10 seconds are my files. You guys really testing your userbase with this new parallel jobs thing. Our CTO is thinking of just going back to Teamcity to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops) the complete list can be found in the following documents:

- [Details of Ubuntu 18.04 agent image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/7fc477ed2018755408f9c03aec06238e5fe6c64d/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-Readme.md) *
- [Details of Ubuntu 20.04 agent image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/7fc477ed2018755408f9c03aec06238e5fe6c64d/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md) *

(*) The above are permalinks to a specific snapshot of code (dated 2022-03-26). For the most current data, switch to the "main" branch in GitHub. Note that files may disappear from the 'main' branch when image gets deprecated.

As of 2022-03-26, both images include the same set of pre-cached docker images which are:

```
alpine:3.12
alpine:3.13
alpine:3.14
buildpack-deps:bullseye
buildpack-deps:buster
buildpack-deps:stretch
debian:10
debian:11
debian:9
moby/buildkit:latest
node:12
node:12-alpine
node:14
node:14-alpine
node:16
node:16-alpine
ubuntu:16.04
ubuntu:18.04
ubuntu:20.04
```

This can also be confirmed by adding a simple task to the pipeline that runs `docker image list`. Here's an example of the command's output ran on `Ubuntu-16.04` agent (before it was deprecated):

```
/usr/bin/docker image list
REPOSITORY                                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                                                 10-alpine           955e0e1f1a41        11 days ago         80.5MB
node                                                 10                  bb78c02ca3bf        11 days ago         908MB
node                                                 12-alpine           afd897e3184b        11 days ago         85.2MB
node                                                 12                  b6f455933a97        11 days ago         913MB
buildpack-deps                                       stretch             c82dad0a8baf        2 weeks ago         835MB
debian                                               9                   92416e205014        2 weeks ago         101MB
debian                                               8                   955c8f8160c2        2 weeks ago         129MB
alpine                                               3.8                 c8bccc0af957        3 weeks ago         4.41MB
alpine                                               3.9                 82f67be598eb        3 weeks ago         5.53MB
alpine                                               3.10                af341ccd2df8        3 weeks ago         5.56MB
jekyll/builder                                       latest              4605d94a6b36        4 months ago        564MB
alpine                                               3.7                 6d1ef012b567        11 months ago       4.21MB
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/node8-typescript   latest              9a948d360778        16 months ago       595MB
```