# Azure pipelines: downloading docker image multiple times

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a single azure pipelines yml that a pipelines that runs many different jobs for testing microservices. We have a single base docker container to make dependency loading much faster.

**The problem is that this image gets downloaded for every stage.** This defeats some of the point of using a docker container if we cant just reuse the image for different stages. Many times loading image might take 1-5 minutes per job/stage.

How can we use the same docker image throughout different stages without having to redownload it?

```yaml
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
  containers:
  - container: azure_pipelines_deploy2
    image: azure_pipelines_deploy2:1.0.0
    endpoint: acr_connection
trigger:
  tags:
    include: [feature/*]
pr: 
  autoCancel: True # indicates whether additional pushes to a PR should cancel in-progress runs for the same PR. Defaults to true
  branches:
    include: [ master ]

stages: 
- stage: OneOfManyStages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because jobs run on seprate agents, thus your image is not available on that machine. Please check [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops).

> A stage contains one or more jobs. Each job runs on an agent. A job represents an execution boundary of a set of steps. All of the steps run together on the same agent. For example, you might build two configurations - x86 and x64. In this case, you have one build stage and two jobs.

You need cache an image on the agent which is [not possible at the moment on hosted agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736596/cached-docker-images-on-hosted-linux-preview-agent).

So to speed up this you have two option for consideration:

- create a step (ideally as template reused across your jobs/stages), to build a docker image using already cached image as a base for your image - it could theoretically speed up the process, but if building your image is time consuming it could end up even in worse result - this simply needs to be checked for your scenario
- use hosted agent and then you will keep your image in the cache, avoiding getting image each time