# I want to delete all docker images but it doesn't work

Tags: docker-image

I used docker and wanted to delete everything

So I tried to remove it but it didn't disappear

```
docker images  
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
SIZE
laravel_app_sample   latest              b5ec6934ff5b        24 minutes ago      852MB
laravel_db_sample    latest              f0a16ec4f305        27 minutes ago      445MB
ubuntu               latest              2ca708c1c9cc        7 days ago          64.2MB
mysql                latest              b8fd9553f1f0        13 days ago         445MB
centos               latest              67fa590cfc1c        5 weeks ago         202MB
nginx                latest              5a3221f0137b        5 weeks ago         126MB
```

I tryed

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a)
```

> unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a)

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

> unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a

```
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
```

> unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a

[How to delete all Docker local Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785585/how-to-delete-all-docker-local-docker-images)
I saw it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker image ls -aq | xargs docker image rm -f