# How do I delete multiple images in docker?

Tags: docker

I have created a lot of images but I don't know how to delete them efficiently.

Does anyone know good command to remove the images smartly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question already had comprehensive answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/4676641) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785784/4676641) some of which were re-iterated below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can try `docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)`

Explanation:

`docker images -q` will list all the image id's. Then you pass all the image id's to
`docker rmi -f`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is what I want!
I only want to remove the images but keep my container~

Comment: careful! you need to add `` wrap docker images -q
like this docker rmi -f  `docker images -q`

Comment: On a Mac you get: ❯ 
unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Answer (score 10):

The following should delete all your unused images and stopped containers:

```sh
$ docker system prune -a
```

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)

Answer (score 4):

At first, you need to delete/stop the running container that is using your image(which one you want to remove).

- `docker ps -a`: To see all the running containers in your machine.
- `docker stop <container_id>`: To stop a running container.
- `docker rm <container_id>`: To remove/delete a docker container(only if it stopped).
- `docker image ls`: To see the list of all the available images with their tag, image id, creation time and size.
- `docker rmi <image_id>`: To delete a specific image.
- `delete rmi -f <image_id>`: To delete a docker image forcefully
- `docker rm -f (docker ps -a | awk '{print$1}')`: To delete all the docker container available in your machine
- `docker image rm <image_name>`: To delete a specific image

To remove the image, you have to remove/stop all the containers which are using it.

- `docker system prune -a`: To clean the docker environment, removing all the containers and images.

N.B: For docker common commands you can see: [docker essential commands](https://github.com/shahincsejnu/docker-stuff#docker-essential-commands)