# Passing the result of a git command as an argument to docker build

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I need to pass the git commit hash to a `docker build` so that it's further passed as an argument to `dotnet build` to be used as suffix for versioning packages.

Inside the `dockerfile`, I have something like this:

```
FROM ...

ARG GIT_COMMIT
ENV GIT_COMMIT=$GIT_COMMIT

...

RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore /p:SourceRevisionId=${GIT_COMMIT}
```

I'm trying to pass the `GIT_COMMIT` argument as follows:

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD) .
```

but this results in the following error:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

What I want is the short version of the hash, so I need to pass `--short` to `git`:

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) .
```

In this case, I get the following:

```
unknown flag: --short
See 'docker build --help'.
```

What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: This should work. I have something similar in my scripts and it works perfectly. Are you sure you run this command in a git repository and `git rev-parse HEAD` produces meaningful output? Other source of possible problems: are you invoking this command from bash console? For example this will fail on Windows.

Comment: I am sure I run it from the right place. If I just run `git rev-parse --short HEAD` in the terminal window, it works as expected. I run this on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure this kind of substitution syntax works well on a Windows shell ?

Comment: To add to the other two comments: what shell are you using ? cmd.exe ? PowerShell ? bash (either directly on Windows, or on WSL) ?

Comment: I'm using Windows Terminal. That's cmd.exe basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `cmd.exe`. You can use:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`git rev-parse HEAD`) do docker build --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=%A .
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226480/3390419) for more information.

Comment: That's great. It worked very well. Thank you!